# Display a SharePoint list row in a table with JS

Tags: custom-list, jslink

I have a SharePoint list with one row containing project info.

- projectnumber
- ProjectName
- ProjectAdmin
- Contracter and so on.

I want to display this as a nice table in the teamsite. I reckon this is done with a display template or Javascript. I tryed this code, but it returns undefined for the custom fields

Please help.

```
(function () {

var itemCtx = {};
itemCtx.Templates = {};

    itemCtx.Templates.Header = "<div><b></b></div><table>";
    itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
    itemCtx.Templates.Footer = "</table>";

itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

})();


function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {

var var_prnummer = ctx.CurrentItem.Prosjektnummer;
var var_prnavn = ctx.CurrentItem.Prosjektnavn;
var var_prleder = ctx.CurrentItem.Prosjektleder;
var var_endret = ctx.CurrentItem.Endret


return "<tr style='background-color: #AEE33B;width: 300px;height: 24px;'><td>Prosjektnummer</td><td>" 

+ var_prnummer + "</td></tr>"
+ "<tr><td>Prosjektnavn</td><td>" + var_prnavn + "</td></tr>"
+ "<tr><td>Prosjektleder</td><td>" + var_prleder + "</td></tr>"
+ "<tr><td>Endret</td><td>" + var_endret + "</td></tr>"

"</span>";

}
```

screenshot.
https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ao_2YX-U1uKUlsxL93IYeHEgIV5ZfA

Comment: You can take reference from here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137444/export-contents-of-a-sharepoint-list-to-a-html-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Danny

```
var var_prleder = ctx.CurrentItem.Prosjektleder[0].title;
```

I had to put `[0].title` at the end to get the right awnser because `Prosjektleder` was an array.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you are not using the correct **internal** Fieldnames

- Open a View
- Open F12 Developer tools
- Execute:

  ```
  ctx.ListData.Row[0]
  ```
- and check what the correct Fieldnames are

You could also add a

```
console.log( ctx.CurrentItem );
```

inside your function, to see what is available

Note: You can only reference List Fields that have been declared in the View

If you need non-View List Item Fields you could massage the data in with a Calculated Column (referencing the required Fields), or do an extra JSOM/REST call to fetch the List Item Fields.